# Delete all the notifications on click

Tags: android, android-notifications

in my app I'm creating 3 notifications (with id 0,1, 2) depending on some data.

I use

```
 setCancel(true);
```

on the notification in order to let the system cancel it on user click.
I would like to cancell all the notifications (id 0,1,2) on the userclick on one of them.
Is this possible?

This is my code about notification creation:

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityMain.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    Notification notification = null;

    builder.setContentTitle(title)
           .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    notification = new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder).bigText(mex).build();

    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [NotificationManager#cancelAll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll()) method

Comment: Yes, I already seen cancellAll method, but I don't know how to use it on the notification click.
Thanks.

Comment: Just add a `PendingIntent` to the notification, and once it is clicked call the method I told you, or if you prefer to cancel just a single notification call `cancel(int id)` instead. Adding an action to the notification: http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#action

Comment: I just edited my first post, adding the code I'm using for the creation of the notification.
I'm already using an intent, how can I update my code in order to do what you suggest? 
Thanks.

Comment: Try to get the `NotificationManager` in the MainActivity and call `cancelAll` method within `onCreate` to test it. It should wipe out all your notifications.

Comment: Isn't possible to do this directly on the click of the notification?
Calling in main activity is like a workaround..

Comment: No, you can not. Calling to MainActivity is what you had in your code, I just was suggesting how to capture and erase all notifications which is your main question on this thread. However, you cannot execute any code in the notification builder, you must provide a `PendingIntent` as an action, and there handle what you want to do. If you prefer, you can use a `BroadcastReceiver` instead in the `PendingIntent`, but remember to use `getBroadcast` instead of `getActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NotificationManager.cancel(int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)) to cancel your notifications when handling the `Intent` from any of the notifications.